# How to create an Add method to store server info to db?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help storing the (multiple) server connection strings to a DB, I need to query them and show all the added servers in a list.

I use NaviCat.

I have seen tutorials on crud, but I don't understand how to add multiple variables to a string that is shown on a list.

What I want in a textbox:
Server ip
user id
port
password

```
"server = 127.0.0.1; user id = system; persistsecurityinfo = True; port = 3308; database = test1; Password = thisisatest21"
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple DB server connections? What do you mean by "i don't understand how to add multiple variables to a string"?

Comment: I need to add/delete connection strings, and query them to show the status of each server. Can't find any tutorials showing how to do this.. Is there any way to save the connection strings locally?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials about how to save something: in SQLite databases, in text files, in memory,.... all that depends on your use case

Comment: Then how do i foreach every row into the connection string? like this:              
"server = dbserver; user id = dbid; persistsecurityinfo = True; port = dbport; database = test1; Password = databasepass"

Comment: Well, like you do it in all foreach loops?